# understanding usage of eval() to evaluate boolean

Tags: javascript

I was just going through the code of timer.js **[HERE](https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer/blob/master/jquery.timer.js#L35)**. and came across the following lines of code:

```
var paramList = ['autostart', 'time'];
for (var arg in paramList) {
    if (func[paramList[arg]] != undefined) {
        eval(paramList[arg] + " = func[paramList[arg]]");
    }
};
```

In the source code its all on one line, but i've made it more readable above , my difficulty is with the usage of `eval`, I.E. the below line of code:

```
eval(paramList[arg] + " = func[paramList[arg]]");
```

now if i add a breakpoint in chrome to the above line and go to the console and paste the line of code i get the following:

```
true
```

How come ? lets have a close look at the statement again:

```
eval(paramList[arg] + " = func[paramList[arg]]");
```

what is the `+` doing here ? converting `paramList[arg]` to a string , in which case eval is being used as follows:

```
eval("paramList[arg] = func[paramList[arg]]");
```

?

or is the plus sign being used for concatenation purpose ? (which i think is very unlikely !)

I have read **[MDN eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)**, but still had doubts.

can anybody explain the breakdown of that statement please ?

Thank you.

Comment: the + is just string concatenation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eval` takes a string. What you have:

```
eval(paramList[arg] + " = func[paramList[arg]]");
```

**The `+` is just string concatenation.**

Is equivalent to:

```
var code = paramList[arg] + " = func[paramList[arg]]"
eval(code);
```

So I'd say it should be equivalent to:

```
global[paramList[arg]] = func[paramList[arg]];
```

Or, in this particular example (with `var paramList = ['autostart', 'time'];)`):

```
if (func['autostart'] != undefined)
    autostart = func['autostart'];

if (func['time'] != undefined)
    time = func['autostart'];
```

Comment: i really just wanted to know if `eval(paramList[arg] + " = func[paramList[arg]]");`  is equal to `eval("paramList[arg] = func[paramList[arg]]");` , my console give the same result for both , but i still had to ask ! , thats all i really wanted to know , thanks for the effort though !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik I have no idea how your console gives you the same result for both. Read my answer again.

Comment: what is global[paramList[arg]] = func[paramList[arg]]; ?

Comment: In Node.js it's a global namespace object. In a browser `window` could be used instead. However the last paragraph of my answer shows that in the actual code, the lexical scope of the name is used.

Comment: whats really happening on that line `eval(paramList[arg] + " = func[paramList[arg]]");` , is a value being assigned or what ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Read the last code bock carefully. This is what the eval expands to.